# Ruby generic filesystem libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filesystems, virtualfilesystem

I am looking for a "Virtual File System" type library for ruby. I want to be able to have a completely generic file system that I can easily switch between using Local files and using S3 or using FTP or something like that. (Identical to VFS for Java)

Has anybody used any type of generic file system for ruby (I just need it to support local files and Amazon S3)

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Vfs (Virtual File System) - it provides simple and unified interface over Local File System, AWS S3, SFTP.

Overview: http://alexeypetrushin.github.com/vfs

S3 samples: http://alexeypetrushin.github.com/vfs/s3_basics.html

Comment: Very nice, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use something at the OS level like [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)? I know of several S3 backends for fuse.

Comment: No, I would much rather not rely on FUSE